# duplicate entry: okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

```
i am getting this error when after integrating the OverAir sdks in Gradle and i dont know which one library is causing a duplicate entry with these sdk files. my project gradle file look like this

compile ('com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5')
compile('com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
compile(name:'onemotion-sdk', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'overair-sdk', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'material-search', ext: 'aar')
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.8.8'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

### but the error is caused by these two OverAir and OneEmotion sdk from lib folder. may its conflicting with Universal image loader library or Picasso, any one can help me, Thanks is advance....!

```
compile(name:'onemotion-sdk', ext:'aar') 
compile(name:'overair-sdk', ext:'aar')
```

Comment: You are not accepted my answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please add these 2 lines in your project level `gradle` file with in `android {}` tag braces

```
configurations{
        all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
        all*.exclude module: 'okio'
    }
```